# MS SQL - Join Multiple Pivots

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I am trying to merge multiple pivots together as a single statement.Could you please help how to.

```
SELECT ID, A as [LglCode-A],B as [LglCode-B],C as [LglCode-C],D as [LglCode-D] from 
             (
                select ID,LglFlg, Code
                from #tmp1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Legal)
                for Code in ([A],[B],[C],[D])
            ) p; 

SELECT ID, A as [MH Code-A],B as [MH Code-B],C as [MH Code-C],D as [MH Code-D] from 
             (
                select ID,[MH Code], Code
                from #tmp1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([MH Code])
                for Code in ([A],[B],[C],[D])
            ) p;
```

I saw this approach from the link, is it the only better way to do so ?
[MS SQL Pivot Another Table Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750475/ms-sql-pivot-another-table-multiple-times)

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest conditional aggregation.  I think this does what you want:

```
select id,
       max(case when Code = 'A' then lglflg end) as legal_a,
       max(case when Code = 'B' then lglflg end) as legal_b,
       max(case when Code = 'C' then lglflg end) as legal_c,
       max(case when Code = 'D' then lglflg end) as legal_d,
       max(case when Code = 'A' then [MH Code] end) as mh_a,
       max(case when Code = 'B' then [MH Code] end) as mh_b,
       max(case when Code = 'C' then [MH Code] end) as mh_c,
       max(case when Code = 'D' then [MH Code] end) as mh_d
from #tmp1
group by id;
```

Comment: no, i would like to merge the pivot as a single statement

Comment: @Dilip . . . This is *much* simpler than anything you would do with `pivot`.  I don't recommend using `pivot` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select distinct ', 
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Code]=''' + CAST([Code] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [Legal] ELSE 0 END) AS [LglCode-' + CAST([Code] as varchar(10)) + '],
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Code]=''' + CAST([Code] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [MH Code] ELSE 0 END) AS [MH Code-' + CAST([Code] as varchar(10)) + ']'
            /*---------------You can add other columns here similarly--------------*/
            FROM #tmp1 
            FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ID, ' + @Cols + '  FROM #tmp1 group by ID' 

--print (@query)
exec(@query)
```

You may need to change a bit here and there as there is no test data available here.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thanks. any source where i could learn these kind of statements ?

Comment: @Dilip Thanks! you can find more details [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns/).